# Cisco - #show inventory vs #show interface

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

I am documenting equipment which requires me to state installed Physical Layer Interface Module (PLIM)/slot and transceivers/interfaces. What confused me is the different information shown between `#show inventory` and `#show interface description`.

1. The information from `#show interface description` doesn't list all interfaces under a slot shown from `#show inventory`. The slot has status ready from `#show platform`.
2. The information from `#show inventory` doesn't list all interfaces which are listed from `#show int description`.

Any reasons for these situations? Any suggestions so that I can documenting without any contradictions? Router is Cisco ASR 12000 series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`show inventory` shows you the device components, part-no. and erial-no.
so you may also see controller´s, Crypto-Modules, SFP's, Power-supplies, etc.

`show interface` shows all interfaces (which may have a protocal attached, for example, IPv4) . This includes interfaces without hardware, like
loopback, tunnel, Ethernet.subinterfaces ( gig 0/1.234 ) ,
and dynamically created (virtual-access, ...) or the stamp of them (virtual-template).

Use "show inventory" "show license" "show hardware" "show diag" "show platform"
to collect the physical infrastructure.

Get "show running" for the Configuration and the allways-be-there interfaces,
including non-physical or interface-templates.

Dont forget to save the IOS Version and Variety which is running.